# Software update never completes

Tags: software-update, leopard, disk-utility

I have an eMac (PPC G4) with 512 MB RAM, running 10.5.8. When I run Software Update, the "Checking for new software..." process never completes. I have tried deleting my `/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/Cache.db` and running Software Update again, with no luck. I have also tried Repairing Disk Permissions from Disk Utility, and that hasn't worked either. Both of those suggestions I got from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/29002/mac-os-x-software-update-gets-stuck)

Any suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line? `softwareupdate --list` to see if it spits out any errors?

Comment: Yep I tried that too. Just freezes just like the GUI

Comment: Also an output from your Console would be helpful to see where the problem might be.

Comment: There is no console output. It just freezes and does not complete lol

Comment: Can you access http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/index.sucatalog from your browser or using curl? (Just to rule out that you can talk to Apple's servers) and if have you tried deleting com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist in `/Library/Preferences/`?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user account and executing the Software Update from that new user?

Comment: Thanks Martín, I tried that but it didn't work yet. Still trying.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the contents of /Library/Receipts somewhere else. I have seen some weird problems caused by corrupted files there a couple of times. Also make sure apps like Little Snitch do not intervene in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the CLI way:

```
sudo softwareupdate -i -a
```

this may help to get more verbose output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This freezes as well, right after the command is issued.

Comment: right after? nothing like `Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2009 Apple` ?? alternatively, if you `man softwareupdate` you'll get a list of options, like a simple `sudo softwareupdate -l` listing and even more useful `sudo softwareupdate -v -i -a` to have a verbose output

Comment: well, yeah I get the 'Software Update Tool' info, but it freezes after that. I believe I tried the `man softwareupdate` but I don't remember what happened lol. I definitely didn't try with verbose output. I'll try that later. Thanks!